# How to Excute Procedure in MySQL Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have c# code to execute query on database. Here is my code.

```
internal string ExcuteQuery(string query, Type type, out int totalCount, out TimeSpan second)
        {
            using (var dbContextTransaction = Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    var index2 = query.LastIndexOf("limit ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                    var isLastLimitNotInBetween = query.Length - 20;

                    if (query.IndexOf(") as data ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == -1)
                    {
                        if (index2 != -1 && index2 > isLastLimitNotInBetween)
                        {
                            query = query.Insert(index2, "\n) as data ");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            query = query.Insert(query.Length, "\n) as data ");
                        }
                    }

                    if (query.Contains("***final_output_query_start***"))
                    {
                        var index =
                            query.IndexOf("***final_output_query_start***", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) +
                            "***final_output_query_start*** ".Length;
                        query = query.Insert(index, Environment.NewLine + "   select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from( ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        query = Environment.NewLine + " select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from( " + query;
                    }


                    Watch.Start();

                    var data = Database.SqlQuery(type, query);

                    // need to do here becuase of the execution flow manage
                    var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.None,
                        new IsoDateTimeConverter {DateTimeFormat = Constants.DateTimeFormat});

                    totalCount = Database.SqlQuery<int>("SELECT  FOUND_ROWS();").First();

                    dbContextTransaction.Commit();

                    Watch.Stop();
                    second = Watch.Elapsed;
                    Watch.Reset();

                    return jsonString;
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    ElmahLogger.Log(exception, "LM api");
                    dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

But Now I want to execute `Mysql Procedure` with the same code. How can I do it?
I tried passing `"call myPrcName()"` in `query` variable.
but giving error of

> "Invalid query"

how do I achieve this?`

Comment: What is the final value of query variable being passed to `Database.Query` method? Did you debug the code and check what changes are made to query variable ? Try running that query value directly against database from workbench.

Comment: Actually I want to add limit 2 (Have to select only 2 records) from result of  procedure. How can I do it?

Comment: Did you try executing stored procedure with limit 2 in workbench? Does it work there?

Comment: No, It is not working there. Please see this - http://prntscr.com/fo68f0

Comment: If it gives error in work bench then how can you expect it to work via C#? It is clear that you can not use limit option with stored procedure call. Either you put limit in the select query in the stored procedure or process only first two rows from all the rows returned by the procedure in C#.

Answer (score 0):

This should call a stored procedure named `MyProcName`.  `SqlCommand` works for both SQL Queries and Stored Procedures and is very flexible and easy to use. See here [How to pass int parameters in Sql commandText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312898/how-to-pass-int-parameters-in-sql-commandtext).  Perhaps you can change your code to use SqlCommand instead of `SqlQuery`. I am not fully sure, there may also be a way to call SP through `SqlQuery`.

```
using (Common.DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandText = "MyProcName";
    dynamic dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    int index = 0;
    List<string> columns = new List<string>();

    for (index = 0; index <= dr.FieldCount - 1; index++) {
/////
    }

}
```